# TwitteR searchTwitter() call not working when in for loop

Tags: r, twitter

I'm currently trying to loop through a searchTwitter() call for each of 21 players in the NBA to get the 100 most recent tweets about them. However, weirdly, the call was working within my for loop of lastMVPs (which is a list of the names), but then stopped after 10 loops through, which would have only been 1,000 API calls. Now the call only works when outside of the for loop. Does anyone have any idea why this is?

For example - this works:

```
searchTwitter("Lebron James", n = 2, lang = 'en')
```

But this does not:

```
for (name in lastMVPs) {
  newitem = searchTwitter(name, n = 100, lang = 'en')
  df = twListToDF(newitem)
  name = df$text
  tweetMatrix = cbind(tweetMatrix, name)
}
```

And I get the error

```
Error in twListToDF(newitem) : Empty list passed to twListToDF
In addition: Warning message:
In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :
  100 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0
```

Which doesn't make sense to me because how can the API be maxed out when it's already working for my call outside of the loop?

Comment: (1) How confident are you that all queries will have at least 100 tweets? Meaning, are you certain they all exist? (2) I suggest using a list, such as `tmtx <- lapply(lastMVPs, function(nm) twListToDF(searchTwitter(nm,n=100))$text)` and consider `cbind`ing later; memory management is a bit cleaner. (3) You might want to consider using `tryCatch` or `purrr::safely` to be more fault-tolerant.

Comment: @r2evans (1) is an excellent point. I had "Giannas Antetokounmpo" in there and I highly doubt there are even 10 tweets with his full name accurately spelled in it.

Comment: If you must use a wide format (I strongly urge you to consider using a tall/long format instead), then at least look into padding the returned vector to a minimum length, such as (within your query/process function), do `length(vec) <- 100L`, which will pad the remainder with `NA`.